# Рекурсивное создание компоновщика из класса

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, рекурсия, компоновщик

Добрый вечер, прошу помочь с композицией из рекурсивных полей класса.
Допустим, у меня есть изделие класса InfoObject, в котором есть атрибут "Состав" типа Collection (по сути таблица), где элементы - InfoObject и могут тоже иметь состав!

Вопрос в том, как мне создать композицию из класса InfoObject, чтобы я рекурсивно (а с рекурсией у меня очень тяжко) пробегался по составу каждого изделия.

то есть это примерно будет выглядеть как-то так

```
    InfoObject pvc = product.GetInfoObject("ActualVersion");

    var compositionList = pvc.GetCollectionElements("ProductBaselineConfigurationItemList").ToArray();
    foreach (var pr in compositionList)
    {
        InfoObject pv = pr.GetInfoObject("ActualVersion");
        if (pv != null)
        {
       //Здесь должна быть рекурсия
        }
    }
```

и примерный шаблон композиции

```
private abstract class Component
{
    protected readonly string Name;

    protected Component(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public abstract void Add(Component c);
}

private class CompositeComponent : Component
{
    private readonly List<Component> _children = new List<Component>();

    public CompositeComponent(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    public override void Add(Component component)
    {
        _children.Add(component);
    }
}

class EndComponent : Component
{
    public EndComponent(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }
    public override void Add(Component c)
    {
    }
}
```

ещё я бы был очень признателен, если вы бы смогли мне помочь реализовать вложенность таких изделий по типу 1.1, 1.2, 1.1.1, 1.2.1, 1.2.1.2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот набросал пример рекурсивного класса (код не соответствует вашему случаю, но суть в целом такая же):

```
    class Component
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Component> Childrens { get; set; }

    public Component(String name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Childrens = new List<Component>();
    }

    public static void RecursiveWork (Component component) {
        //выполняем какую-либо работу над текущим компонентом
        Console.WriteLine("processing " + component.Name + " ...");

        //далее обрабатываем все дочерние компоненты
        foreach (Component child in component.Childrens)
            Component.RecursiveWork(child);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Component Root = new Component("Root");
        Root.Childrens.Add(new Component("Root.1"));
        Root.Childrens.Add(new Component("Root.2"));
        Root.Childrens.Add(new Component("Root.3")
        {
            Childrens = new List<Component>()
            {
                new Component("Root.3.1"),
                new Component("Root.3.2"),
                new Component("Root.3.3")
                {
                    Childrens = new List<Component>()
                    {
                        new Component("Root.3.3.1"),
                        new Component("Root.3.3.2"),
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Component.RecursiveWork(Root);
    }
}
```

Что касается вложенной нумерации компонент, то на ум приходит решение через статик список:

```
static List<int> currentComponentNumeration;
```

В рекурсивной функции делаем следующее:

- когда начинаем обработку дочерних компонент, добавляем этот список число "1" (нумерация начинается с 1)
- когда обработали очередной компонент, последний элемент списка увеличиваем на 1
- когда обрабатываемые компоненты закончились, удаляем последний элемент списка

Соответственно, чтобы получить номер текущего компонента, к примеру в виде строки "2.1.3", остается только обойти этот список по порядку